# PHP simplexml_load_file case return false

Tags: php, phpunit, simplexml

I make unit test with phpunit (100% cover) for my PHP application and I have this :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soapResponse); 
if (false === $xml) {
    throw new \Exception('invalid XML'); 
}
```

I don't find a test case with `simplexml_load_string` return `false`.

If you have a solution... Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as John C noted, invalid xml will cause simplexml_load_string to return false and generate warnings. Additionally you may want to disable those warnings and store them. To do so you can use libxml_use_internal_errors and libxml_get_errors.

```
<?php
$soapResponse = 'invalid_xml';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soapResponse);
if (false === $xml) {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    echo 'Errors are '.var_export($errors, true);
    throw new \Exception('invalid XML');
}
```

So the output is:

```
array (
  0 => 
  LibXMLError::__set_state(array(
     'level' => 3,
     'code' => 4,
     'column' => 1,
     'message' => 'Start tag expected, \'<\' not found
',
     'file' => '',
     'line' => 1,
  )),
)
```

which may help you to identify problematic part in XML. This is extremely useful when XML is large.

Comment: Thanks, I had "simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found" But "libxml_use_internal_errors(true);" resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any invalid XML will cause `simplexml_load_string` to return `false`:

```
$soapResponse = 'invalid';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soapResponse); 
var_dump($xml);
// output: bool(false)
```

Note that this will also generate warnings.